# add one item to an array instead of listing the entire array all over again using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

trying to get my list from my array to show up when page loads anad when you do add an item to list the item at the bottom of the list. currently my script writes the enitre array all over again when you click the submit button.
check out my fiddle to follow what i am talking about. please any help would be great:)

http://jsfiddle.net/trav5567/2ebothpb/

```
function myFruit() {
    var Fruit = ['apple', 'bannanna', 'rasberry', 'watermelon', 'grape', 'orange'];
    $('#addFruit').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var flag = true;
        var val = $('#fruitAdd').val();
        for (var i = 0; i < Fruit.length; i++) {
            if (Fruit[i] == val) {
                flag = false;
                console.log('already entered this item');
            }
        }
        if (flag)
            Fruit.push(val);
        loopArray();
    });

    function loopArray() {
        var fruitList = $('ul.fruit');
        var arrayContainer = $('.arrayContainer');
        for (var i = 0; i < Fruit.length; i++) {
            fruitList.append('<li>' + Fruit[i] + '</li>');
        }
    }
}
myFruit();
```

Comment: Your `if(flag)` is missing it's `{..}`s.. actually I don't know if that is intentional, I'll indent the code for you so it's easier to see

Comment: ya i copied the code from someone else and he didnt add the brackets but for some readon the code still works. i will add in my code thank you.

Comment: The `{ brackets }` are not required for a single statement block in JS. Even the newline is not required, `if (true) alert("It's true!")` will alert every time. However, you may find that you have a personal preference for consistent styling of `if`s and wish to always use brackets, but it is not required.

Comment: thanks for the info, didnt know you didn't need the brackets

Comment: i will keep using them just for readability and my preference of choice;)

Comment: @GregL Yes, but I'm not sure `loopArray` was meant to be invoked if `flag` is _falsy_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `loopArray` function just empty your `list` before adding new values.

```
function loopArray() {
        var fruitList = $('ul.fruit');
        $(fruitList).empty();// this line added
        var arrayContainer = $('.arrayContainer');
        for (var i = 0; i < Fruit.length; i++) {
            fruitList.append('<li>' + Fruit[i] + '</li>');
        }
    }
```

If you want one empty `li` should be there use following for that line.

```
$(fruitList).html('<li></li>')
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/2ebothpb/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for something more like this

```
function myFruit() {
    var fruits = ['apple', 'bannanna', 'rasberry', 'watermelon', 'grape', 'orange'];

    function addFruit(fruit, $list) {
        $list || ($list = $('ul.fruit'));
        $list.append('<li>' + fruit + '</li>');
    }

    function addAllFruit() {
        var $list = $('ul.fruit');
        for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
            addFruit(fruits[i], $list);
        }
    }

    addAllFruit(); // generate the list of hardcoded fruit

    // add handler for user defined fruit
    $('#addFruit').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newFruit = $('#fruitAdd').val();
        if (!newFruit) {
            console.warn('No fruit given');
        } else if (fruits.indexOf(newFruit) !== -1) {
            console.warn('Fruit already exists');
        } else {
            fruits.push(newFruit);
            addFruit(newFruit);
        }
    });
}
myFruit();
```